# use value (string) from table 1 to refer columns of another table

Tags: sqlite

I have two tables:
T1:

```
id  name  field serial# 
1   A1    xx    123 
2   A1    yy    123
3   A1    zz    123
4   A2    xx    124
5   A2    yy    124
6   A2    zz    124
```

T2:

```
serial#   xx  yy  zz 
123       0   1   1
124       1   0   1
```

I want to write a query such that the result table would look like:

```
id  name  field serial#
1   A1    yy    123
2   A1    zz    123
3   A2    xx    124
4   A2    zz    124
```

I tried to write a query which looks like:

```
select * from T1, T2
from ...
where T2.(T1.field) <> 0  <-- This is where I never get the syntax right
...
```

Answer (score 0):

SQLite cannot access columns dynamically; you have to check each one manually:

```
SELECT ...
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.serial = T2.serial
       AND ((T1.field = 'xx' AND T2.xx) OR
            (T1.field = 'yy' AND T2.yy) OR
            (T1.field = 'zz' AND T2.zz))
...
```

Alternatively, same algorithm with a [CASE expression](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#case):

```
SELECT ...
FROM T1
JOIN T2 ON T1.serial = T2.serial
       AND CASE T1.field
           WHEN 'xx' THEN T2.xx
           WHEN 'yy' THEN T2.yy
           WHEN 'zz' THEN T2.zz
           END
...
```